# USPS Download shipping labels for multiple package with same trackiing number using PHP

Tags: usps

I am using DeliveryConfirmationV4 APT to download label. But in my service there are multiple packages in single shipments.  i can find rates for multiple packages into single request.

Now how to create lables for that packages with same tracking number Or one master track number like fedex given.

Can anybody solve this issue.